# strip certain character from lines in a textfile

Tags: file, awk

I have a text file (generated by a script each week) with multiple lines, where I'd like to strip out certain characted, that differ each week. The files can look something like this;

```
Community S05E05 Geothermal Escapism SD TV.avi
Community S05E02 Introduction to Teaching SD TV.mp4
Supernatural S09E12 Sharp Teeth SD TV.avi
Elementary S02E11 Internal Audit SD TV.mp4
```

What I want removed is the season/episode numbering, and the quality and filetype. How to do this on a synology machine (busybox linux).

Comment: Is there perl available on this box? Awk, sed and other GNU tools are higly limited in functionality in busybox to my knowledge.

Comment: and what's your expect output? Give the detail.

Comment: It got solved like this;
perl -ne '/(.*) S..E.. (.*)SD TV.*/i;print "$1 - $2\n";' < /tmp/v$DATE-weekly.txt
So it seems that perl functions on/in busybox. 

What I wanted was something like
Community - Geothermal...
Community - INtroduction and so on.

Comment: @mgsk you have been misinformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the comment you posted about a perl solution, it sounds like this is all you need:

```
$ awk '{$2="-";NF-=2}1' file
Community - Geothermal Escapism
Community - Introduction to Teaching
Supernatural - Sharp Teeth
Elementary - Internal Audit
```

Comment: Thanx, alll suggestions are welcome, since I'm trying to learn shell programmin. Sed/AWK and reg.exp's are a genuine hell for me :)